# Rename default branch in TortoiseHG

Tags: mercurial, branch, tortoisehg

Is it possible to rename 'default' to 'production' in TortoiseHG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do it directly from the [Tortoise2.0+ settings](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.0/settings.html), but through the command-line `hg`.
As documented in [hgbook](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/hgbook/1.6/managing-releases-and-branchy-development.html):

> Mercurial lets you assign a persistent name to a branch.
>   There always exists a branch named default. Even before you start naming branches yourself, you can find traces of the default branch if you look for them.
>
> To start working with [named branches](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Branch), use the hg branches command

```
$ hg branch production
marked working directory as branch production
$ hg branch
production
```

Check then if that change is reflected in TortoiseHg

Answer (score 6):

You cannot rename a branch in Mercurial (or TortoiseHg for that matter). What you do instead is to start a new branch called `production` and base it on the current `default` branch.

You can do this in TortoiseHg 2.0, where you

1. Click the row representing the working directory
2. Click the branch button
3. Click to open a new branch
4. Fill in the branch name and click OK
5. Enter a commit message and click Commit.

[image: TortoiseHg commit dialog]

This will create a new branch with the name `production`. The old `default` branch will remain and you can thus put new features there before merging them into `production` when they're stable.